# How to use Source Code Management in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to whenever I start the `Jenkins pipeline` build, the job will either `clone`/`pull` from the Git.

But I don't know how to do this in Jenkins Pipeline, besides hard coding `git clone $url` , `git pull` (if exists) in one of the early `steps` of the first `stage`.

Answer (score 2):

This is pipeline configuration and Jenkins will do the magic. You just need to create a Pipeline Task and in Configuration in the Pipeline section, select your SCM and put your repo URL.

[image]

When you perform a build, Jenkins will pull and checkout the code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I do what you said, I need to specify the declarative/scripted pipeline in the `jenkinsfile` instead of the console right?

Comment: You can select Pipeline Script in the Definition combo and in the right corner you will see _try sample Pipeline..._ with a Github + Maven example, or you can even click on Pipeline Syntax at the bottom of the script texta area and generate your own code for git/whatever. This allows you to writte your script there instead of a Jenkinsfile